# Adjective ending with -er

Tags: adjective

Let's take the adjective "teuer" for example, the indefinite masculine form of it is "ein teurer" right? Why isn't it "ein teuerer"? Why was the "e" omitted?

Does the same go for the comparative form of the adjective "teuer"?

Answer (score 4):

Only **some** adjectives ending in ‘-er’ behave the way you indicate, and they are irregular in that regard. Besides ‘teuer’, examples include ‘sauer’ and ‘(un)geheuer’. So, it would be ‘teuer’ – ‘teurer’ – ‘am teuersten’, and ‘sauer’ – ‘saurer’ – ‘am sauersten’. (Note that the ‘e’ is back in the superlative form.)

As far as I know, ‘teuerer’ and ‘sauerer’ are *possible*, but ‘teurer’ and ‘saurer’ are preferable. According to the Duden, ‘sauberer’ and ‘saubrer’ are equally fine.

All this said, the rule is that the ‘e’ is **not** omitted in adjectives ending in ‘-er’. Examples include ‘sicher’, ‘finster’, ‘koscher’, ‘heiter’, and ‘munter’.

As with all irregular words / forms, it’s always a bit difficult to say *why* all this is the case; but I believe it’s mostly phonetic. Roughly, after the ‘eu’ and ‘au’ in ‘teuer’ and ‘sauer’, the ‘rer’ sound is preferable to ‘erer’. I’m no expert on this, though: perhaps somebody else will be able to tell you this more precisely.

Comment: Vielen danke :)

Comment: The difference I notice is that the irregular adjectives have a vowel right before the *er*, so it's very likely that there are phonetic reasons. Also, I'm sure *finstrer Wald* has been used in poetry or fairy tales.

Comment: In some dialects the "e" is also omitted for the words ‘sicher’, ‘finster’, ‘heiter’ and ‘munter’. (I don't know about ‘koscher’.) Google found texts of Morgenstern (and Goethe?) omitting the "e" - however often an apostrophe is written then: "ein finst'rer", "ein munt'rer" ...

Comment: Te German Language generally tends to avoid "erer", when words are declined or adapted. Another good example is the "Zauberin", who would be called "Zaubererin", if you strictly appliedthe language rules.